# Append column with condition

Tags: pandas

I have 2 df. first columns = [`value`, `Date`]. second columns = [`diff`, `Date`]

Need to create new column in first df with values from column `diff` second df where second.Date == first.Date, else default 0 value.

How can this be done concisely using pandas?